# How do I send JSON request AND post form data request together?

Tags: php, json, rest, postman

So this is an API which should accept the following parameters in POST request:

```
token (as form data)
apiKey (as form data)
{
"notification": {
    "id": 1,
    "heading": "some heading",
    "subheading": "some subheading",
    "image": "some image"
     }
 } (JSON Post data)
```

Now my problem is that i'm not able to send the form data and JSON data together in the same POST request. Since, the form-data uses `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and JSON needs to have `Content-Type: application/json` I'm not sure how do I send both of them together. I'm using Postman.

EDIT:

So the api will call the function `create` and I need to do something like this:

```
public function create() {


    $token = $this -> input -> post('token');
    $apiKey = $this -> input -> post('apiKey');
    $notificationData = $this -> input -> post('notification');

    $inputJson = json_decode($notificationData, true);
    }
```

But instead I'm not able to get the JSON data and form data together.

I have to do this to get JSON data **only**

```
public function create(){
$notificationData =  file_get_contents('php://input');
$inputJson = json_decode($input, true);  
} // can't input `token` and `apiKey` because `Content-Type: application/json`
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Have you tried simply sending the JSON directly without setting the content type to `application/json`?

Comment: It looks like a form post with 3 keys having 3 string values.

Comment: Are you trying to design this API, or this an existing API you're trying to talk to…?

Comment: This is not very clear. The issue is not "how to send", but "what does the server expect to receive". Normally, a JSON request will be read by servers as the full body of the request, formatted as JSON. POST data is read as full body of the request, formatted in the `key=val&key2=val2` style. The two are incompatible, it's like saying "I want a vegetarian bacon sandwich". You need to know how the server is interpreting your request. The server might be expecting GET-style parameters with your JSON body (since GET params are not send in the request body).

Comment: @RaxWeber Posted the code.

Comment: @deceze I'm trying to design one. Please check the edit.

Comment: @Amadan So I want to send `token=val1&apiKey=val2` AND also `notification` as JSON data. It's not possible to send them together, right?

Comment: Of course it is, in many different ways. Most of them are nowhere near standard. You can send exactly what you said in OP, but then you'd need to have custom code in both client and server to construct and parse the body (I do not suggest you do this). You can do what I said before and send token and API key as GET-style params, and reserve the body for JSON. You can require previous auth, and carry an auth token in a cookie, so that you only need to send JSON in the actual request. You can put the token and API key inside the JSON.

Comment: `token` and `apiKey` **have** to be in the POST data separately, not inside the JSON request. Can you please elaborate on GET-style param thingy? How do I send the data in GET request? Also, this code is written by a developer who has worked on it, I'm thinking if there's some kind of changes I need to do in the headers field or something so that my data is accepted? @Amadan

Answer (score 3):

Several possibilities:

1. Send the token and key as query parameters and the JSON as request body:

   ```
   POST /my/api?token=val1&apiKey=val2 HTTP/1.1
   Content-Type: application/json

   {"notification": ...}
   ```

   In PHP you get the key and token via `$_GET` and the body via `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))`.
2. Send the token and key in the `Authorization` HTTP header (or any other custom header):

   ```
   POST /my/api HTTP/1.1
   Authorization: MyApp TokenVal:KeyVal
   Content-Type: application/json

   {"notification": ...}
   ```

   You get the header via, for example, `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` and parse it yourself.
3. Make the token and key part of the request body (not very preferred):

   ```
   POST /my/api HTTP/1.1
   Content-Type: application/json

   {"key": val1, "token": val2, "notification": ...}
   ```

Comment: Hi, the specification is that `token`and  `apiKey` are POST data. Solution #1 shouldn't be used then, right?

Comment: To be clear: Solution 1 puts the data into the **URL query string**. That is ***not*** "GET data", even if you access it via `$_GET` in PHP. That's bad naming on PHP's part. An HTTP request with the `POST` method is a POST request. Data in the **URL query string** is ***not*** "GET data".

Comment: So, no, there's no reason not to use solution 1.

Comment: and to access the query parameters from string  `$token = $this -> input -> post('token');` this would be the way, right?

Comment: I don't know what framework you're using, so I cannot tell you what API that framework has to access URL query parameters.

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter framework and testing the API with Postman.

Comment: Well, looks like you're supposed to use `$this->input->get()` then. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data

Comment: Yes, it worked. Can you please tell me how does #2 work? Like how do I access header params?

Comment: `$this->input->server()` I'd guess…

Comment: Unable to do it, I'll look it up though. I'll go with the 1st one. Many thanks to you!